# Getting error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII during building (Ivy) of a project in Jenkins

Tags: java, svn, ant, character-encoding, jenkins

I have the correct encoding in SVN and i see the correct text while opening the file in SVN.
The above error is thrown during Cobertura compile in Jenkins server ( log below). When i was doing a jenkins build locally, i could not see this error.

I am using Java 1.7 and have integrated Sonar to Jenkins.I am using IVY to manage dependencies inside the project. I searched a lot in the web and Stack Overflow but could only find answers related to Maven.

Would appreciate if someone could help.

Full Log Below

```
init:
     [echo] ### Making default directories ###
     [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/hd/dt/var/jenkins/workspace/A/ProjectName/build/classes

cobertura.compile:

     [echo] ### Setting Compile Classpath ###
     [javac] /opt/hd/dt/var/jenkins/workspace/A/ProjectName/src/com/cs/mm/ab/common/util/Constants.java:119: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
    [javac]     public static final String THANK_YOU = "Thank you for choosing Restie?s for your ";
    [javac]                                                                                  
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/opt/hd/dt/var/jenkins/workspace/A/ProjectName/build/ant/build.xml:32: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/hd/dt/var/jenkins/workspace/A/ProjectName/build/ant/cobertura-build.xml:51: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Are your files encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: No, its CP1252 in Eclipse. This has been working before until Java 1.7 upgrade.

Comment: Did not mean to duplicate. I had gone through those answers. They were all related to updating Maven and POM. I am not using Maven but Apache Ivy.

Comment: @NishM I don't believe it's relevant how `javac` is invoked (whether through Maven or something else); it's that it encounters a character with unexpected encoding. The linked answer should provide a resolution to your problem.